# Bitcoin data by country?

Tags: raw-data, database, historical-trade-data, academic-research

I am a political science graduate student looking to do research on bitcoin and cryptocurrency. To do so, however, I need data. While many datasets provide wonderful histories of bitcoin price and trade across time, I need data across space too for the type of research I am looking to do. I have found a large cache of data by countries' fiat currency used in transactions in the localbitcoins exchange here that does what I'm looking for, as an example: https://coin.dance/volume/localbitcoins/. I have also found graphs tracking traffic for major exchanges from Statista, but I haven't had any success finding or accessing the raw data. See here: https://www-statista-com.libdata.lib.ua.edu/statistics/944261/share-of-bittrex-visitors-by-country/ (same thing goes for the data for the data for Bithumb, Huobi, and Upbit on this site).

It doesn't matter to me so much what data exists (purchases, traffic, anything--I'm new to this stuff!) so long as there is some data out there on bitcoin by country. I also understand that this is a high ask considering the anonymity and decentralization of the blockchain, which are what attracted me to the topic in the first place. tl; dr **where can I find bitcoin raw data by country?**

Comment: try UsefulTulips.org for some good peer-to-peer trade volume data by geography. He doesn't do much exchange volume though.

Answer (score 1):

I've written an open-access academic paper on Bitcoin full node data [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11187-019-00309-8), and the data is in the [Electronic Supplements](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1007%2Fs11187-019-00309-8/MediaObjects/11187_2019_309_MOESM1_ESM.xlsx). I explain in the [Appendix](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11187-019-00309-8#appendices) how I get and prepare the data if you need more fine-grained analyses. The data is country-year from 2014-2018. Good luck!

PS: The data includes Bitcoin merchant data worldwide too. Please do cite the paper after use.